# why serial code is much faster than parallel?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I wrote this serial and parallel code for Goldbach's Conjecture but the serial code is faster than the parallel. Could someone help me with this ?
Is there a way do parallel faster?

This is serial code :

```
class GoldbachSerial
{
    public  bool IsPrime(long number)
    {
        double maxCheck = Math.Sqrt(number);

        for (long i = 2; i <= maxCheck; i++)
        {
            if (number % i == 0) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public string GetTwoPrimeNumbers(long number)
    {
        for (long i = 2; i <= number / 2; i++)
        {
            if (IsPrime(i) && IsPrime(number - i))
            {
                return string.Format("{0}={1}+{2}", number.ToString("N0"), i.ToString("N0"), (number - i).ToString("N0"));
            }
        }
        return "not found";
    }
}
```

This is Parallel code:

```
class GoldbachParallel
{
    ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount
    };


    private bool IsPrime(long number)
    {
        long maxCheck = (long)Math.Sqrt(number);
        bool result = true;

        Parallel.For(2, maxCheck + 1, parallelOptions, (i, loopState) =>
        {
            if (loopState.IsStopped) return;

            if (number % i == 0)
            {
                result = false;
                loopState.Stop();
            }
        });

        return result;
    }
    //   private static int atomic = 0;
    public string GetTwoPrimeNumbers(long number)
    {
        string result = "not found ";

       // ParallelLoopResult r = 
        Parallel.For(2, (number / 2) + 1, parallelOptions, (i, loopState) =>
        {
            if (loopState.IsStopped) return;

            if (IsPrime(i) && IsPrime(number - i))
            {
                //  Interlocked.Increment(ref atomic);
                //  loopState.Break();
                result = string.Format("{0}={1}+{2}", number.ToString("N0"), i.ToString("N0"), (number - i).ToString("N0"));
                loopState.Stop();
            }
        });
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are overparallelizing. The overhead of parallelism in your case is far more than the gain.

Comment: Do you have 2500000 cores? Not sure why you expect CPU intensive work to run faster if you don't have free CPU to run work on...

Comment: USE.  A.  SIEVE.  Algorithm improvements will pay off many times faster than naive Parallel.For.  Also, sieves tend to be embarassingly parallel

Comment: @BenVoigt Or better yet, just use a math library that's already spent an enormous amount of time writing as optimized of an implementation as possible for determining if a number is prime, or a sequence of prime numbers, rather than trying to roll your own.

Comment: as others said dont make every simple task parallel. ive used normal `IsPrime` and parallel `GetTwoPrimeNumbers` and the task was done in `0.3` for the number `1234567`, and the task finished in `0.6` for the non parallel version. although the speed of your algorithm highly depends on numbers. one can take ages and another can take just a millisecond. use the Sieve algorithm that can be well written in parallel. but again it should be used for finding one prime number at a time.

Answer (score 4):

Which do you think would be faster, adding together 10 pairs of single digit numbers yourself, or finding 10 other people, giving them all a pair of numbers to add, having them all add those numbers, and then give you back the answer?  Will it always be faster to have more people doing the work?

Now, if you had had a harder problem for each other person to solve such that you'd gain more time having productive work done at the same time than time lost in the overhead of moving the work between people (or CPUs) then it'll be beneficial.

Likewise, some problems aren't suited to parallelism, although that's not your problem here.  9 women can't make a baby in a month, after all.  No amount of parallelism will reduce the time of that activity.